# Simple Social Icons plugin not work on my blog

Tags: plugins

I am using http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-social-buttons/ Plugin, but its not working properly. This plugin worked on GoPress theme, but is not working on Ribbon theme, which I downloaded from http://www.spiceupyourblog.com/

#### Problem with plugin:

**Social icon button does not display on archives. But in Gopress theme it displayed**

this is a code that display archives,

```
<article class="article">
    <div id="content_box" class="home_page">
        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class="post excerpt <?php echo (++$j % 2 == 0) ? 'last' : ''; ?>">
                <div class="post-date-ribbon"><div class="corner"></div><?php the_time('d M Y'); ?></div>
                <header>
                    <h2 class="title">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </h2>
                    <div class="post-info">
                        <div class="author_mt hp_meta"><span class="mt_icon"> </span><?php _e('By ','mythemeshop'); ?><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></div>
                        <div class="cat_mt hp_meta"><span class="mt_icon"> </span><?php the_category(', '); ?></div>
                        <div class="comment_mt hp_meta"><span class="mt_icon"> </span> <a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>"><?php comments_number(' 0 Comments',' 1 Comment',' % Comments'); ?></a></div>
                    </div>
                </header><!--.header-->
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="nofollow" id="featured-thumbnail">
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?> 
                        <?php echo '<div class="featured-thumbnail">'; the_post_thumbnail('featured',array('title' => '')); echo '</div>'; ?>
                    <?php } ?>
                </a>
                <div class="post-content image-caption-format-1">
                    <?php echo excerpt(56);?>
                </div>
                <div class="readMore"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php _e('Read More','mythemeshop'); ?></a></div>
            </div><!--.post excerpt-->
        <?php endwhile; else: ?>
            <div class="post excerpt">
                <div class="no-results">
                    <p><strong><?php _e('There has been an error.', 'mythemeshop'); ?></strong></p>
                    <p><?php _e('We apologize for any inconvenience, please hit back on your browser or use the search form below.', 'mythemeshop'); ?></p>
                    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                </div><!--noResults-->
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($options['mts_pagenavigation'] == '1') { ?>
            <?php pagination($additional_loop->max_num_pages);?>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <div class="pnavigation2">
                <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '&larr; '.'Older posts', 'mythemeshop' ) ); ?></div>
                <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts'.' &rarr;', 'mythemeshop' ) ); ?></div>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>      
    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: "not work properly" is not much of a trouble ticket. Please improve this question.

Comment: means social button not display on archives of the post

Comment: it not work only on Ribbon Thame ,its display on anther theme like Gopress ,AccentBox etc.

Comment: Delete your comments. They aren't relevant anymore.

Comment: That plugin hooks to `the_content` and `the_excerpt` which should be the correct hooks to do what it needs to do. I have to assume that the theme is doing something strange with the content on the archive page. Find and post the them code that displays the archives.

Comment: not possible bye me because am a junior developer.

Comment: No, and that is a terrible, terrible idea. Never give out credentials on the internet.

Comment: i found the code but its to long so i cant add in comment

Comment: I added code that display the archivs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`excerpt` is not a WordPress function. That theme has rolled its own "excerpt" function and has broken something.

Replace `echo excerpt(56);` with `the_excerpt();` and you should see your icons.

I have no idea what else that `excerpt` function does or why the theme developer thought it necessary, so there may be consequences to altering that that will have to track down, debug, and fix. If you post the code for that function it may help.

Comment: its not my problem,i have live link of this blog, http://mysmartphoneapps.gtumca.com/ open this,an on the front page i want belove  or above social button on each post on front page.

Comment: an s_ha_dum realy sorry i am using this plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-social-buttons/

Comment: So you aren't using the plugin you said you were. Got it. [Edit] your question to reflect to correct information!

Comment: @NikunjJagad : see the edit